# roscd, rospack find work, rosmake fails?

Tags: rosbuild, ros-groovy, rosmake, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I'm a little stumped on this one.  Ubuntu 12.04, ROS groovy, building with rosbuild (porting legacy packages).

I have a package that we've developed that shows up 100% perfectly using a roscd or a rospack find.  The problem is, when doing a roslaunch or a rosmake, I get the following errors:

[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] No package or stack specified.  And current directory 'track_obj' is not a package name or stack name.
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: []
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/youbot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130715-141430
[ rosmake ] Expanded args [] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

It doesn't matter if I put the package name there, or move to the directory and give it "." it always fails.

My $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH both includes a parent folder and now the actual package folder for good measure.

Why might rospack find work, but rosmake fail?

We're working on some object tracking stuff using OpenCV and so we have some code that works as a standalone C++ project, and also has a ROS wrapper.  I'm not sure that part's relevant.

If there are any files I can provide to help diagnose this problem, let me know.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67375/roscd,-rospack-find-work,-rosmake-fails?/) by [aespielberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/147/aespielberg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2013-07-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-07-15**:
Does the package folder contain a `CATKIN_IGNORE` file? If yes, you have to remove that file.

**Comment by [aespielberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/147/aespielberg/) on 2013-07-15**:
That's it!  You should answer for reals so I can give you karma that you can't spend anywhere :-p

**Comment by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on 2013-07-15**:
Are you doing the rosmake and roslaunch in the correct folder. I think the issue can only pertain to the CATKIN_IGNORE just as Dirk mentioned or if you are doing it in the wrong folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does the package folder contain a CATKIN_IGNORE file? If yes, you have to remove that file.

If the file gets regenerated you will need to update your packages. catkin 0.5.69 contains a fix for in-source builds (which is basically what rosmake does). The package might not be available in the public yet but only in shadow-fixed.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2